# Matplotlib axhline: linewidth changes X position of line

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, visualization

I've observed some weird effects of using `linewidth` param in `axhline` from `matplotlib.pyplot`. I want to make line bolder, but this param makes line wider too.

For example, `linewidth = 1`:
[image]

and `linewidth = 25`:
[image]

X position of these blocks makes really big difference for me. I can't accept errors as big as that. Do you have any ideas how to make this line bolder without changing their X position?

Comment: Yes, my fault - I use axhline in my code. I updated question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the lines you are drawing are limited between a minimum and a maximum value, then you should use [**`matplotlib.pyplot.hlines`**](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hlines.html) in place of [**`matplotlib.pyplot.axhline`**](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.axhline.html). Moreover you can control the line endings style with [**`capstyle`**](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.Collection) parameter:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.hlines(y = 1, xmin = 1, xmax = 2, color = 'red', linewidth = 1, label = 'linewidth = 1, default capstyle')
ax.hlines(y = 2, xmin = 1, xmax = 2, color = 'green', linewidth = 25, capstyle = 'projecting', label = 'linewidth = 25, "projecting" capstyle')
ax.hlines(y = 3, xmin = 1, xmax = 2, color = 'blue', linewidth = 25, capstyle = 'butt', label = 'linewidth = 25, "butt" capstyle')

ax.set_xlim(-1, 4)
ax.set_ylim(-1, 5)

ax.legend(frameon = True)

plt.show()
```

[image]